# How to get MIN value and latest date [Sql Server 2008]

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am able to get the latest date but I could not get the Minimum value. what I am trying to get here is I want to display the Minimum value for each `findingAbbr` for each patient with their latest creation date and time of that minimum value. Can somebody please suggest me what I am doing wrong with this query?

Thank you for any help!!!

```
WITH cteRankedData As
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        a.AccountID
         ,e.FindingAbbr
         ,min(e.Value) as Value
         ,e.CreationTime
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.AccountID, e.FindingAbbr ORDER BY e.CreationTime DESC) As RN

FROM      dbo.PatientVisitInfo a with (nolock)
JOIN      dbo.Assessment d with (nolock) ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
JOIN      dbo.Observation e with (nolock) ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
WHERE
         a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
     AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
     AND e.Value <> ''
     AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_PEEPSet','A_KR_RT_FI02%','A_FIO2%Set','A_FIO2%', 'A_Vent Mode')
     AND e.CreationTime >= DATEADD(d,-1, GETDATE())
     group by a.AccountID ,e.FindingAbbr, e.CreationTime)
SELECT
         AccountID
         ,FindingAbbr
         ,Value
         ,CreationTime


FROM
    cteRankedData
WHERE
    RN = 1

ORDER BY
    AccountID
  ,CreationTime
;
```

Result I am getting:

```
AccountID   FindingAbbr Value   CreationTime
1           _FIO2%        40   1/7/15 1:55 PM
2           A_FIO2%       60   1/7/15 8:20 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    60   1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     8    1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 9:47 AM
3           A_FIO2%Set    70   1/7/15 7:21 AM
4           A_KR_RT_FI02% 30   1/6/15 2:54 PM
4           A_FIO2%       30   1/7/15 9:35 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 10:22 AM
```

all results:

```
AccountID   FindingAbbr Value   CreationTime
1           A_FIO2%       40   1/7/15 1:55 PM
2           A_FIO2%       60   1/7/15 8:20 AM
2           A_FIO2%       60   1/7/15 8:20 AM
2           A_FIO2%       100  1/7/15 1:31 AM
2           A_FIO2%       100  1/7/15 3:30 AM
2           A_FIO2%   Other:70 1/7/15 4:11 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    60   1/7/15 3:49 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    60   1/7/15 9:45 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    60   1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    100  1/7/15 1:29 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     8    1/7/15 1:29 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     8    1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 9:45 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     8    1/7/15 3:49 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 3:49 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 9:45 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 1:29 AM
3           A_FIO2%Set    70   1/6/15 3:09 PM
3           A_FIO2%Set    70   1/7/15 7:21 AM
4           A_FIO2%       30   1/7/15 4:26 AM
4           A_FIO2%       30   1/7/15 9:35 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/7/15 9:53 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/7/15 3:55 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/6/15 7:22 PM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/6/15 11:02 PM
4           A_KR_RT_FI02% 30   1/6/15 2:54 PM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/6/15 7:22 PM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/6/15 11:02 PM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 3:55 AM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 9:53 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 9:53 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 3:55 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/6/15 11:02 PM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/6/15 7:22 PM
4           A_Vent Mode   CPAP 1/6/15 2:54 PM
```

the result i want:

```
AccountID   FindingAbbr  Value   CreationTime
1           A_FIO2%       40   1/7/15 1:55 PM
2           A_FIO2%       60   1/7/15 8:20 AM
2           A_FIO2%Set    60   1/7/15 9:47 AM
2           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 9:45 AM
2           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 9:47 AM
3           A_FIO2%Set    70   1/7/15 7:21 AM
4           A_KR_RT_FI02% 30   1/6/15 2:54 PM
4           A_FIO2%       30   1/7/15 9:35 AM
4           A_FIO2%Set    45   1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_PEEPSet     5    1/7/15 10:22 AM
4           A_Vent Mode   CMV  1/7/15 10:22 AM
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of separating your min Value and max creationTime, why not combine them both in your ROW_NUMBER() windowing function

```
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.AccountID, e.FindingAbbr 
ORDER BY e.Value, e.CreationTime DESC)
```

ROW_NUMBER() 1 will be the latest creation time of the lowest value for that particular accountID and FindingAbbr.

Answer (score 0):

You were close.  Remove the `min` on the `Value` column in your cte, add `e.Value` to `group by`, and add `value` to your row_number order by for the `RN` column.  This should give you the minimum value for each findingAbbr, along with the most recent date.

```
WITH cteRankedData As
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        a.AccountID
         ,e.FindingAbbr
         ,e.Value as Value
         ,e.CreationTime
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.AccountID, e.FindingAbbr ORDER BY e.Value ASC, e.CreationTime DESC) As RN
    FROM      dbo.PatientVisitInfo a with (nolock)
    JOIN      dbo.Assessment d with (nolock) ON a.PatientVisit_oid = d.PatientVisit_oid
    JOIN      dbo.Observation e with (nolock) ON e.AssessmentID = d.AssessmentID
    WHERE
            a.VisitTypeCode='IP'
        AND a.VisitEndDateTime is null
        AND e.Value <> ''
        AND e.FindingAbbr IN ('A_PEEPSet','A_KR_RT_FI02%','A_FIO2%Set','A_FIO2%', 'A_Vent Mode')
        AND e.CreationTime >= DATEADD(d,-1, GETDATE())
    GROUP BY a.AccountID ,e.FindingAbbr, e.CreationTime, e.Value
)
SELECT
     AccountID
    ,FindingAbbr
    ,Value
    ,CreationTime
FROM
    cteRankedData
WHERE
    RN = 1
ORDER BY
    AccountID
  ,CreationTime
;
```